# Windows phone live background

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8

What I want to do is a live background for my tic tac toe main menu which should put Xs and Os randomly in any button  what happens is that the program just freeze and when I tried tracing it the code inside the dispatcher never get excuted

```
public partial class MainPage : PhoneApplicationPage
{
    Random random;
    private Button[] bts;
    private int counter;

    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        counter = 0;
        bts = new[] { _1, _2, _3, _4, _5, _6, _7, _8, _9 };
    }

    private void Button_Click_1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/Page1.xaml", UriKind.Relative));
    }

    private void Button_Click_2(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/Page3.xaml", UriKind.Relative));
    }

    private void About_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/Page4.xaml", UriKind.Relative));
    }

    private void form_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        random = new Random();
        while (true)
        {
            Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(()=>
            {    
                bts[random.Next() % 9].Content = (counter % 2 == 0) ? "O" : "X";
                counter++;
            });
       }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
while (true) Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(...);
```

This is an infinite loop; it will freeze your program forever. (actually, until it runs out of memory in the dispatcher queue)

Don't do that.

Comment: ywa but i want to keep putting Xs and Os untill the user clicks a button what should i do ?? that's the question

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.threading.dispatchertimer.aspx